# Convert a vector of 3D point to homogeneous representation in Eigen

Tags: 3d, geometry, eigen, homogenous-transformation

I have a buffer containing N 3D points stored as `[XYZXYZXYZ ... XYZ]`.

This buffer can be directly mapped to a `Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, N>` using Eigen::Map.
Since I will transform the points using affine transformations (i.e `Eigen::Matrix4f` matrices) I would like to map the same buffer to an eigen structure that allows me to consider the buffer as a `Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, N>` matrix where the last row only contains 1s, i.e. each single point is represented by the homogeneous vector [X Y Z 1].

Is there a convenient way to do this without **copying the original buffer** or **applying the transformation on each single point**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply [homogenous()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html#a635f8f9087821d4b3dcebd2997b5f9bd) on each column like this:

```
Matrix4f mat = ...; // your affine transformation stored as a 4x4 matrix
float *data = ...;  // your raw buffer storing 3D point as [XYZXYZXYZ...]
mat * Map<Matrix<float, 3, Dynamic> >(data,3,N).colwise().homogeneous()
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does the job. I was missing the broadcast operation colwise.
To clarify the answer: take the matrix and consider it as a collection of column vectors (colwise), then apply homogeneous to each column vecotrs.

Comment: Where do `mat` and `data` come from?

Comment: I have two Frames A and B. I have generated Rotation Matrix(R) and translation matrix(t). Now how to generate Homogeneous Transfomation? I'm using C++. Any help is greatly appreciated.